# Switch (Button) throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-button

I know this question already exists, but I tried serveral solutions and none worked for me.

In my case, I need a `Switch` Button in the ActionBar.

- I tried to manually add a minSdk Verision
- I tried to use the id of the `item` in the defined xml

Edit: The exception-point in the code is marked with a comments. It's in the mainactivity. :)

Here is some of my code:

**mainactivity:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_minepedia_main);

        switchButton = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_button);

        //The following line throws an exception, because switchButton
        //is null, even though I tried to take it on the upper line.
        switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        //The following is a local boolean variable
                if (isChecked) {
                    ONLINE_MODE_ENABLED = true;
                } else {
                    ONLINE_MODE_ENABLED = false;
                }

            }
        });
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; --> main_actions.xml
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**mainactivity_layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Minepedia_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/items_button"
            android:onClick="startItemsMenu" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about_button"
            android:onClick="startAboutScreen" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/update_offline_button"
                android:onClick="startOfflineUpdate"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/offline_sync_info"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**main_actions.xml (menu):**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:title=""
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
        />
</menu>
```

**switch_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff="Offline"
        android:textOn="Online"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
08-20 17:45:52.902    5534-5534/com.nubage.minepedia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nubage.minepedia, PID: 5534
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.nubage.minepedia.Minepedia_main.onCreateOptionsMenu(Minepedia_main.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:489)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:853)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What line throws an exception? Add logs to the question

Comment: @vokilam: There is a comment for this in the mainactivity-code. :) But I should have given a notice for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the answer by 'ρяσѕρєя K' but change his following line of code:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.switch_button);
```

to this:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch); //the id was changed!
```

That should get rid of the NullPointerException, hope this helps :)

So you should have something like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_minepedia_main);
} 

@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actions, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
    switchButton = (Switch)item.getActionView();

    switchButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener({

    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    //The following is a local boolean variable 
            if (isChecked) {
                ONLINE_MODE_ENABLED = true; 
            } else { 
                ONLINE_MODE_ENABLED = false; 
            } 

        } 
    }); 

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Additionally change this line:

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
```

to this:

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
```

That is within your menu xml. If you apply that change then you are using the switch button provided by android and that must work.

Comment: I also tried this, but I cannot get rid of the NullPointer with this change. :(

Comment: @TrudleR Do you need your own layout for the switch button?
I just recently put a switch in my action bar without any problem, however I didn't use my own layout I just used the standard switch (on/off) that android provides.

Comment: @TrudleR Could you maybe post/update your code of your mainactiviy (java)?

Comment: It's still up to date, just a little more uncommented code (a little mess there atm but basically the same). :)

Comment: @TrudleR Look at my answer again...does your code look like that? :)

Comment: Yeah, it still crashes at start. :( Thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: Could you post your log? or what do you mean by 'at start'? no problem

Comment: I added it to the end of my quetstion. ATM I resetted everything to what ρяσѕρєя K said.

Comment: Could you change this line:
        android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
to this:
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"/>
That is within your menu xml.
Just to see whether it has something to do with your custom layout, because if you apply the change then you are using the switch button provided by android and that must work.

Comment: Dude... That did it...... I cannot say how much I thank you!! :) I have no idea why, but now it works. Finally! :) Thank you veeery much! If you edit your answer I will mark it as the chosen one and +1.

Comment: @TrudleR I added the comment to my answer at the end (I guess that's what you meant). No problem, I am glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `Switch` button is inside `main_actions.xml` so you should use `menu.findItem` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to access views from Menu as:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actions, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.switch_button);
    switchButton = (Switch)item.getActionView();

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but I still get a NullPointerException @ ´switchButton = (Switch)item.getActionView();´