# How to add click event on Android Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, icons

I have added one star icon on Action Bar. Now I want to add click event on that star. If the star is clicked then it should be bright or Turned ON which is OFF by default. And if that star is ON and clicked, then it should go to OFF. I am not getting any idea how to perform onClick event on action bar.

Comment: how did you add the start to the actionbar?

Answer (score 3):

You have a good example here.

[Action Bar Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: done these all but in my action bar, I have star image icon where I want to perform onClick operation.

Comment: this doesn't anwer the question, it's only a link to action bar official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To add `onClickListener` to a view in your `action bar` you have to create a reference to that `view` first and then in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method you can register the `onClickListener`.
See the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398686/switch-button-throws-nullpointerexception/25403464#25403464). Its the same principle, you're simply using a 'star icon' instead of a switch.